# ionic 3 infinite scroll is not working until content scroll to top and then bottom

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, infinite-scroll

I am trying to load some more data in ionic 3 project. The infinite scroll is working only for the first time. And then it is stop working until the page scroll to top and then bottom.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-scroll style="width:100%;height:100vh" scrollY="true">
        <ion-list *ngIf="posts.length>0">
            <button *ngFor="let post of posts" ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
            <img [src]="getPostImage(post)">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
    </button>
        </ion-list>
        <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Loading..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

**TypeScript**

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    this.getCategoryPosts(infiniteScroll);
}

getCategoryPosts(infiniteScroll=null){
       this.api.getCategoryPosts({
        id : this.topic.id,
        limit : this.limit,
        page:this.page,
        success:(posts)=>{
          this.zone.run(()=>{
            if(this.page >1){
              this.posts = this.posts.concat(posts);
            }else{
              this.posts = posts;
            }
              this.page++;
              if(infiniteScroll!=null)
                  infiniteScroll.complete();
          });

        },
        error:(error)=>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<ion-infinite-scroll>` does definitely not work well inside `<ion-scroll style="width:100%;height:100vh" scrollY="true">`, at least for the following Ionic 3 versions:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (./node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

Within the `<ion-scroll>` area of `height` `100vh` it is required to scroll upwards to the top, before the next infinite scroll event can be triggered. Other values for `height` result in the same problem.

My best guess is, that the required height setting for the `<ion-scroll>` area conflicts with content size changes from the added infinite scroll items.

If you can live with a fully scrollable `<ion-content>` and have enough post items in your `<ion-list>` for reaching the infinite scroll [threshold distance](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#input-properties) you can remove `<ion-scroll>` completely.

This was the only solution, that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that works if you don't want a list the full height (100vh) of the screen.  Set the height of the `<ion-scroll>` to say `70vh` and then on every successful infinite scroll, when new items are added to the list, add `4vh` to the height of the `<ion-scroll>` element.

So with a:

```html
<ion-scroll id="list-scroll" style="height: 70vh">
```

Then once the new items are loaded by your component:

```js
scrollHeight += 4;
document.getElementById('list-scroll').setAttribute('style', 'height:' + scrollHeight + 'vh');
```

It doesn't seem to matter how tall you make the `<ion-scroll>`