# ionic infinite scroll doesn't concat the resutls

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic infinite scroll to get more posts every time reach the bottom

it works fine, but it replace the results not concatenating it

here is the code

```
page=0

  getAllposts() {

    const url = `${this.API_URL}/getallposts?page=${this.page}`;

    return this.http.get<any[]>(url);
  }

getAllList() {
  this.getAllposts().subscribe(data => {
    this.showPosts = this.showPosts.concat(data) as PostModel[];

  
  });
} 



loadData(event) {

setTimeout(() => {
this.getAllList()
    event.target.complete();
  }, 2000);

this.page++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `for loop` instead of `cancat`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.showPosts.push(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: I dont have a problem with for loop; I think the result should be use concat to join each other

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481393/ionic-3-infinite-scroll-is-not-working-until-content-scroll-to-top-and-then-bott?rq=1 will this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spread operator` here..

```
this.showPosts = [...this.showposts,...data];
```

[Reference](https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-javascript-b9e4a8b06fab)